# Mysql command returns no errors and doesn't import the sql file. Why?

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm executing on a Centos Linux server this command:

```
mysql -u root -p mydatabase < dump.sql
```

I enter the password. It seems that all is ok because I absolutely get no errors, no messages that something happened. But sadly, the file is not imported!

Tryed in different ways:
-Putting the sql file in another location. 
-Creating the DB first and than without the DB. 
-Avoiding the dbname
-Adding max_allowed_packet=800M in /etc/my.cnf (because the file is 490mb)
-Restarted Mysql. But nothing to do. No errors, no import. I'm stuck and in panic. What to do? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already created database then use below steps to import data from .sql file

DataBase to use:

```
 use DataBaseName;
```

Give the source file path

```
source /path/to/dump.sql;
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This led me to the answer but I had to split the database in different SQL files too. Imported it in MySqlWorkbench and exported again. I think that it was related to some errors in the SQL but very strange that no errors displayed at all.

Comment: This might be because your dump file have more than one database in it, if this the case then you need to create separate dump files for each DB then **source** it using the above steps.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried this command and I see that rows are inserted but when I check the tables of the database I find nothing. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score -1):

please check your dump file it may be empty

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).